# why does data format changes from superset when exported to csv

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, apache-superset

I used D3 format as "Duration in ms(66000=>1m 6s)" for one of the columns in Superset.
But when I try to download the same in CSV the format changes by itself and does not remain same.

D3 format in Superset= 924y 36d 51m 28s
CSV format = 2.91424E+13